# Options in function definition not working with a second set of square brackets?

Tags: functions, options

If I define, for example,

```
f[OptionsPattern[{}]] := OptionValue[a]
```

Then the output for `f[a -> 1]` is 1.

However, in my code, I have a function that must be called using the syntax `f[some parameters][some other parameters]`, and I want to add options to the **second** set of square brackets. So I tried:

```
g[][OptionsPattern[{}]] := OptionValue[a]
```

But then, the output for `g[][a -> 1]` is `OptionValue[a]` instead of 1. I'm not sure why this is not working. Shouldn't `OptionsPattern[{}]` match **any** set of options, no matter where they are located?

How can I add options that can be provided in the second set of square brackets instead of the first?

Comment: I believe that this cannot be achieved. For the example you provided one could additionally define `g[OptionsPattern[{}]] := OptionValue[a]` and then `g[][a -> 1]` "works". I think it is generally advised to stay clear of `SubValues` (which `g[x][y]` implies). Is it possible to refactor the function?

Comment: Unfortunately it would be impossible to avoid this syntax without rewriting the entire code from scratch. I'm considering simply "simulating" options by looking for explicit patterns in the form of option->value and then parsing the options manually. Is there any simple / built-in way to do so without using `OptionsPattern[]`?

Comment: PS: What exactly are `SubValues`?

Comment: Re `SubValues` have a look at [Section 2.2.5 Composite variables and SubValues](http://www.mathprogramming-intro.org/book/node92.html) of Leonid Shifrin's excellent [book](http://www.mathprogramming-intro.org/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the more explicit 3-argument form of `OptionValue`:

```
ClearAll[g];
Options[g] = {a -> 1};
g[][opts : OptionsPattern[]] := OptionValue[g, {opts}, a];
g[][]
g[][a -> 2]
```

> 1

> 2

Or:

```
ClearAll[g];
g[][opts : OptionsPattern[{}]] := OptionValue[{}, {opts}, a];
g[][a -> 2]
```

> 2

Or if you want default option values without defining options for `g`:

```
ClearAll[g];
With[{rules = {a -> 1}},
  g[][opts : OptionsPattern[rules]] := OptionValue[rules, {opts}, a]
];
g[][]
g[][a -> 2]
```

> 1

> 2

Answer (score 2):

`OptionsPattern` apparently does not work for `SubValues`.

One possible solutions is to use an `Association` for option-like behavior

```
g[][opts_Association] := opts["a"]
g[][<|"a" -> 1|>]
(* 1 *)
```

Of course, if you desire the more complex features of options then this will not be too helpful (unless you want to re-implement all the features for this hack).